# Can I use trim() with imagettftext() in php?

Tags: php, fonts, gd

I need to line break in png file witch create by php function : imagettftext(); 
it work good for me but i need to line break like:

```
    $arrText=explode("\n",wordwrap($text,20,"\n"));

    $y=5; //vertical position of text
    foreach($arrText as $arr)
    {
        imagestring($image,10,15,$y,trim($arr),$white);
      $y=$y+15;
    }
```

but i can't use my custom font with imagestring().

what the best solution?

Comment: imagettftext returns an array of coordinates. exactly what do you expect to be able to `trim()` in that? trim() expects a STRING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use :

```
$arrText=explode("\n",wordwrap($text,50,"\n"));

$y=120; //vertical position of text
foreach($arrText as $arr)
{
    imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 40, $y, $mycolor, $font, trim($arr));
 // imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
  $y=$y-40;

}
```

And it was use full